# Where does the number 67 in the nuclear protein/antigen Ki-67 come from? Why not 66 or 68?

Tags: molecular-biology, cancer, antibody

I have read in [in the original paper](https://doi.org/10.1002/ijc.2910310104) that in the year 1983 a research group in Kiel, Germany (that's where the Ki- in the name comes from) developed monoclonal mouse antibodies against Hodgkin lymphoma cells in multiple 24-well plates. If I understand correctly they were able to isolate antibodies from 63 wells and divided them into 493 microtiters into several 96-well microtitre plates. Of these 493 titres, 164 cell batches were chosen for further investigation and expanded. Somehow Ki-67 emerged from there, but why this number? Who gave it that name and why?

A teacher once told us in med school, the cells producing the antibodies were found in well 67, but I cannot find any source to back up that claim.

Comment: There's [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00428-017-2258-0), but who knows where these authors got the idea from...

Answer (score 5):

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ki-67_(protein)) "The name is derived from the city of origin (Kiel, Germany) and the number of the original clone in the 96-well plate".

Comment: That statement in the wikipedia article is unsourced ...

Comment: Yes that's the legend, but I want details...